# Data not getting loaded in Jqgrid when session state is state server/outproc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, session-state, jqgrid-asp.net, mvcjqgrid

I have an MVC 5 application. I have used Jqgrid at multiple places. Recently, we have decided to move from Inproc session state to Outproc/State Server session state. But, after migrating, data stopped getting loaded in my Jqgrid. I tried using the web developer tool to check if any error is getting logged, but I am not getting any error there.

This is the change I have made in my web.config:

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer"
      stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"
      cookieless="false"
      timeout="20"/>
```

Everything else works as expected. Am I missing out on some setting?
Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Main solution is allow remote connection from registry.

To allow remote connection:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\aspnet_state\Parameters\AllowRemoteConnection set value to 1
Restart ASP.NetStateService from systemroot\Microsoft.NET\Framework\versionNumber\aspnet_state.exe.    try this

Comment: Not working. I even tried rebooting system after change. Still not working